# What could be my issue with Selenium and Juptyer Notebook?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, jupyter-notebook, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to use selenium webdriver in a Jupyter notebook. I get the following [Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ABJ08.png) when running:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
```

I've uploaded the [chrome driver](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) to my [Jupyter Notebook Folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gNOuX.png), so the path should be the same,
and I have selenium installed.

I don't understand how the path could be the problem.  I followed the same procedure in Spyder and had no issues.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried exactly what you explained and the problem is that your chromedriver.exe is in a Folder(Selenium Test). Try putting it in your root folder and it should work.